# Link to a external website like Facebook in Java Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, url

I am new to Java Spring framework. I use controller to set URLs to connect to other pages, like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "loginMember")
```

But what if I want to set a link connect to a specific website like www.facebook.com? What should I do?

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView method() {
        return new RedirectView("redirect: the URL you want");

}
```

Comment: Or, more simply and cleanly, just return `new RedirectView("url to redirect to")`